# Python stream.tell() returns incorrect position

Tags: python, file, newline

Tried to use **tell()** to get the cursor position after reading a line. Seems it has problem with **text mode** and **\r**. Am I misusing the method or it's a bug? Thanks.

Tested with python2.6, 2.7, 3.3 and all have the same output.

```
import io

with io.open('a', 'w') as fo:
    fo.write(u'abc\n')
    fo.write(u'def\r\n')
    fo.write(u'hij\r')
    fo.write(u'klm')

print('*io.open rb*')
with io.open('a', 'rb') as fo:
    print('--%r--%d' % (fo.readline(), fo.tell()))
    print('--%r--%d' % (fo.readline(), fo.tell()))
    print('--%r--%d' % (fo.readline(), fo.tell()))
    print('--%r--%d' % (fo.readline(), fo.tell()))


print('*io.open rt*')
with io.open('a', 'rt') as fo:
    print('--%r--%d' % (fo.readline(), fo.tell()))
    print('--%r--%d' % (fo.readline(), fo.tell()))
    print('--%r--%d' % (fo.readline(), fo.tell()))
    print('--%r--%d' % (fo.readline(), fo.tell()))
```

Output: (Not sure what the **340282367000166625996085689099021713421** is)

```
*io.open rb*
--b'abc\n'--4
--b'def\r\n'--9
--b'hij\rklm'--16
--b''--16
*io.open rt*
--'abc\n'--4
--'def\n'--9
--'hij\n'--340282367000166625996085689099021713421
--'klm'--16
```

Comment: What platform? This looks like an overflow bug.

Comment: Probably related to the following: [On Windows, tell() can return illegal values (after an fgets()) when reading files with Unix-style line-endings. Use binary mode ('rb') to circumvent this problem.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.tell)

Comment: I am on Mac OS X 10.9.3.

Comment: Just noticed it's `io.open` rather than the built-in. In that, case, probably relevant: [Return the current stream position as an opaque number. The number does not usually represent a number of bytes in the underlying binary storage.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.tell) The number isn't required or expected to be understandable.

Comment: @user2357112, thanks. This is actually reproducible with the built in open, io.open, codecs.open.

Comment: I thought the built-in was supposed to do that too, but I didn't find the note in the documentation for the `tell` method on the built-in file objects. It might be in the C `ftell` documentation; the built-in file object docs say `tell` is "like `stdio`'s `ftell`".

Answer (score 1):

There are three types of EOL (End of line) in text files:

- windows: \r\n
- unix (linux): \n
- mac: \r

you have to use the correct EOL with the correct format.

- try this to create a unix format file: io.open('a', 'w'),
- or this to create a unix format file: io.open('a', 'wb'),
- and do not use '\r' neither unix nor windows format:

windows format file:

```
            import io

            with io.open('a', 'w') as fo: #this will be a windows format file
                fo.write(u'abc\n')
                fo.write(u'def\n')
                fo.write(u'hij')
                fo.write(u'klm')


            print('*io.open rb*')
            with io.open('a', 'rb') as fo:
                print('--%r--%d' % (fo.readline(), fo.tell()))
                print('--%r--%d' % (fo.readline(), fo.tell()))
                print('--%r--%d' % (fo.readline(), fo.tell()))
                print('--%r--%d' % (fo.readline(), fo.tell()))

            print('*io.open rt*')
            with io.open('a', 'rt') as fo:
                print('--%r--%d' % (fo.readline(), fo.tell()))
                print('--%r--%d' % (fo.readline(), fo.tell()))
                print('--%r--%d' % (fo.readline(), fo.tell()))
                print('--%r--%d' % (fo.readline(), fo.tell()))

            >>>

            *io.open rb*
            --'abc\r\n'--5
            --'def\r\n'--10
            --'hijklm'--16
            --''--16

            *io.open rt*
            --u'abc\n'--5
            --u'def\n'--10
            --u'hijklm'--16
            --u''--16
            >>>

            import io

            with io.open('a', 'wb') as fo: #this will be a unix format file
                fo.write(u'abc\n')
                fo.write(u'def\n')
                fo.write(u'hij')
                fo.write(u'klm')

            print('*io.open rb*')
            with io.open('a', 'rb') as fo:
                print('--%r--%d' % (fo.readline(), fo.tell()))
                print('--%r--%d' % (fo.readline(), fo.tell()))
                print('--%r--%d' % (fo.readline(), fo.tell()))
                print('--%r--%d' % (fo.readline(), fo.tell()))

            print('*io.open rt*')
            with io.open('a', 'rt') as fo:
                print('--%r--%d' % (fo.readline(), fo.tell()))
                print('--%r--%d' % (fo.readline(), fo.tell()))
                print('--%r--%d' % (fo.readline(), fo.tell()))
                print('--%r--%d' % (fo.readline(), fo.tell()))

            >>>
            *io.open rb*
            --'abc\n'--4
            --'def\n'--8
            --'hijklm'--14
            --''--14

            *io.open rt*
            --u'abc\n'--4
            --u'def\n'--8
            --u'hijklm'--14
            --u''--14
            >>>
```

as you can see the results are always the same, without that strange long number

Comment: Thanks. I do know there are three types of new line separators. I mixed them together because I wanted to test how io.open handles them in a simple way. Even I only use '\r' in one file, the *tell* method still returns wrong result.